# Test class example for Push Topic

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

I am unable to get 95-100% test coverage for below class

here is my class

```
global class BT_Invoicing_New_Override_Crtl {

    public ApexPages.StandardController stdCon;
    public BT_Invoicing__c btinvoice{get;set;}
    public Static Integer BtjoblstSize;
    public Double Local_DFE_Quantity;
    public Double Local_Invoice_Cost_excl_vat;
    public String recordId;
    BT_Invoicing__c btinvoiceRecord;
    Public Static String btEstimateNumber;

    public BT_Invoicing_New_Override_Crtl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        stdCon= controller;
        btinvoice= (BT_Invoicing__c)stdCon.getRecord();
        recordId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    } 

    public PageReference Save(){
    try{

        btinvoiceRecord= (BT_Invoicing__c)stdCon.getRecord();


            if(btinvoiceRecord.Invoice_Cost_excl_vat__c==null)
            Local_Invoice_Cost_excl_vat=0;
         else
            Local_Invoice_Cost_excl_vat=btinvoiceRecord.Invoice_Cost_excl_vat__c;

          if(btinvoiceRecord.DFE_Quantity__c==null)
             Local_DFE_Quantity=0;
          else
              Local_DFE_Quantity=btinvoiceRecord.DFE_Quantity__c;

     if(btinvoiceRecord.Pay__c=='Yes'&& ( Local_Invoice_Cost_excl_vat- Local_DFE_Quantity > 0)
                                         && btinvoiceRecord.Reject_Invoice__c==false && btinvoiceRecord.Invoice_In_Query__c==false)
          btinvoiceRecord.Invoice_Status__c='PAID-DFE';
     else if(btinvoiceRecord.Pay__c=='Yes'&& (Local_Invoice_Cost_excl_vat- Local_DFE_Quantity==0) 
                                         && btinvoiceRecord.Reject_Invoice__c==false && btinvoiceRecord.Invoice_In_Query__c==false)
          btinvoiceRecord.Invoice_Status__c='Paid';
     else if(btinvoiceRecord.Pay__c=='No' && btinvoiceRecord.Reject_Invoice__c==false && btinvoiceRecord.Invoice_In_Query__c==false)
          btinvoiceRecord.Invoice_Status__c='Active';



        upsert btinvoicerecord;

        PageReference pageref = new Pagereference('/'+btinvoicerecord.id);
        pageref.setRedirect(true);
        return pageref;

        return null;
      }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,ex.getDMLMessage(0));
        ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
        return null;
    }    
  }

  public PageReference SaveandNew(){
    try{
        stdCon.Save();  
        return new PageReference('/'+stdCon.getRecord().getSObjectType().getDescribe().getKeyPrefix()+'/e?');

      }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,ex.getDMLMessage(0));
        ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
        return null;
    }    

  }

  @RemoteAction
 Public Static Integer GetEstimateListsize(String btestimateno)
  {
         List<BT_Job__c> Btjoblst=[Select Id,Name,Estimate_No__c From BT_Job__c Where  Estimate_No__c=:btestimateno];
         BtjoblstSize=Btjoblst.size();
         System.debug('BtjoblstSize='+BtjoblstSize);
         return BtjoblstSize;
  }


}
```

n this is my test class

```
@istest
public class BT_Invoicing_New_Override_Crtl_Test {

     public static testmethod void myTestUnit1(){
      PageReference pageRef = Page.BT_Invoicing_New_Override;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        BT_Invoicing__c btInvObj = new BT_Invoicing__c();
        btInvObj.Invoice_Cost_excl_vat__c=55.20;
        btInvObj.DFE_Quantity__c=45.30;
        btInvObj.Pay__c='Yes';
        btInvObj.Reject_Invoice__c=false;
        btInvObj.Invoice_In_Query__c=false;

        insert btInvObj;

          ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(btInvObj);
       BT_Invoicing_New_Override_Crtl sic = new  BT_Invoicing_New_Override_Crtl(sc);
      sic.Save(); 
     } 
     public static testmethod void myTestUnit2(){
      PageReference pageRef = Page.BT_Invoicing_New_Override;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        BT_Invoicing__c btInvObj = new BT_Invoicing__c();
        btInvObj.Invoice_Cost_excl_vat__c=45.30;
        btInvObj.DFE_Quantity__c=45.30;
        btInvObj.Pay__c='Yes';
        btInvObj.Reject_Invoice__c=false;
        btInvObj.Invoice_In_Query__c=false;
        insert btInvObj;



         ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(btInvObj);
       BT_Invoicing_New_Override_Crtl sic = new  BT_Invoicing_New_Override_Crtl(sc);
      sic.Save(); 
     } 
     public static testmethod void myTestUnit3(){
      PageReference pageRef = Page.BT_Invoicing_New_Override;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        BT_Invoicing__c btInvObj = new BT_Invoicing__c();
        btInvObj.Invoice_Cost_excl_vat__c=00.00;
        btInvObj.DFE_Quantity__c=00.00;
        btInvObj.Pay__c='No';
        btInvObj.Reject_Invoice__c=false;
        btInvObj.Invoice_In_Query__c=false;
        insert btInvObj;



         ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(btInvObj);
       BT_Invoicing_New_Override_Crtl sic = new  BT_Invoicing_New_Override_Crtl(sc);
      sic.Save(); 
     } 
    public static testmethod void myTestUnit4(){


        BT_Invoicing__c btInvObj = new BT_Invoicing__c();
        btInvObj.Invoice_Cost_excl_vat__c=10.00;
        btInvObj.DFE_Quantity__c=10.00;
        btInvObj.Pay__c='No';
        btInvObj.Reject_Invoice__c=false;
        btInvObj.Invoice_In_Query__c=false;
        insert btInvObj;
       BT_Invoicing__c btInvObj1=[select id , Invoice_Status__c from  BT_Invoicing__c where id=:btInvObj.id];

        PageReference pageRef = Page.BT_Invoicing_New_Override;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        Test.startTest();

      ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(btInvObj1);
       BT_Invoicing_New_Override_Crtl sic = new  BT_Invoicing_New_Override_Crtl(sc);
      sic.SaveandNew();



       }
}
```

I need to increase the code coverage, it's not covering remote action method and catch block
please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't necessarily in your unit test, it's in your code. Some of the code **cannot** be covered, because it is logically impossible to reach. You need to learn how to read code to determine where problems are. For example:

```
    return pageref;

    return null;
```

How do you expect the last line to be called, ever? It can never happen because the previous line to exit the method, guaranteed. Also, try-catch may be impossible to test, so you may have to deal with losing coverage there. 95-100% is not a realistic goal for any code that has error handling, but you can improve your odds by paying attention to obvious logical fallacies.

As for the rest, you're going to likely need a lot more unit tests. Probably close to 10 or so. You can get coverage for most of it, but it will take a lot of code to do so. You might be able to optimize your branch logic to use fewer alternative lines, which is one trick I often use for improving coverage.